# Replacing Add to cart button with custom button shortcode on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know how to replace add to cart button on woocommerce with custom button shortcode.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback. In this case, *this question is a little bit too vague*, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need add something like this to the functions.php in the theme folder (`/wp-content/theme-name/functions.php`)

```
// The custom replacement button function
    function custom_product_button(){
        // HERE your custom button text and link
        $button_text = __( "Custom text", "woocommerce" );
        $button_link = '#';
        
        // Display button
        echo '<a class="button" href="'.$button_link.'">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }
    
    // Replacing the single product button add to cart by a custom button for a specific product category
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_single_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
    function replace_single_add_to_cart_button() {
        global $product;
    
        // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'custom_product_button', 20 );
        }
        // For all other product types
        else {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_product_button', 30 );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My shortcode is " [yith_ywraq_button_quote] " How to i link this shortcode to the code.

Comment: At first, please mark my answer as correct. Secondly, please this is not an chatting app. Next time please Google it, or make a new question here. You can run your shortcode in PHP by 'do_shortcode()'

Comment: So in custom_product_button() function you will run 'echo do_shortcode([your-shortcode]);

Comment: First of all, Asking him to mark the answer will indeed increase your reputation but next time *do not* say *"please mark my answer as correct."* when the OP is still asking for some more clarification. Second, low quality questions like this are not recommended to be answered. Answering good questions are more likely to be useful for people in the future

Comment: np, Goodluck on your journey and have a great day! :D